# Query in Excel without heading - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, heading

Is it possible to export data into an excel sheet without the heading?

I know SET HEAD OFF works in SQL Developer
example:
SET HEAD OFF
select count (customers)
from cust;

but how do I get the data without the heading in Excel if I am using the Microsoft Query wizard and ODBC?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming excel 2010.

After importing data, select table. On ribbon chose Design and clear Header Row field.